# Does Ord a allow me to use "=="?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I  was doing some test functions to understand a little more about Haskell, and I did this:

```
constroiMSet :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a,Int)] 
constroiMSet( x:x1:xs) |x1==x =[(x,2)]
```

The thing I don't get is why this function works. This function has `Ord a` but it uses `==` to compare `a`. Isn't `Ord a` only for `>=`, `<=`, `<`, `>`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If we look at the [definition of the `Ord`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Ord) class, we see:

```
class Eq a => Ord a where
  compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
  (<) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (<=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (>) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (>=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  max :: a -> a -> a
  min :: a -> a -> a
```

So this means that every type `a` where `Ord a`, also means `Eq a`. So an `a` that supports `Ord`, also supports `Eq` and thus `(==)` and `(/=)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask you something, when you say: “every type `a` where `Ord a`, also means `Eq a`. In terms of logic, I would interpret ‘Ord a -> Eq a`. However, the arrow in the constraint is in the order direction. Is there a standard way to interpret the constraint I am missing?

Comment: @F.Zer: yes, in terms of logic, the arrow should be reversed. But here the arrow is more of a constraint, so it says, in order to be an instance of `Ord a`, it is constrained to have `Eq a` as well. But as a logical arrow, it needs to be `<-`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the type class definition:

```
class Eq a => Ord a
```

Now suppose the data type:

```
data OTT = One | Two | Three
```

If I derive the type directly to Ord with `deriving Ord` or I give an implementation it will brake, because I didn't say how to implement `Eq`, so one posible way to do it will be:

```
data OTT = One | Two | Three deriving Eq, Ord
```

Then `Eq` is mandatory because of the constraint `class Eq a =>`

Comment: ooh so if  i want like x==b if i do( x>=b && x<=b ) its the same thing so the compiler acepts also x==b , nice

Comment: @JoaoParente hahaha nice one, it not what I tried to say, you made me laugh

Comment: Let me add something to the answer for you too

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The compiler doesn't know that `==` is supposed to represent equality and `<=` / `>=` are supposed to represent less-or-equal / greater-or-equal, respectively. In particular, the compiler won't rewrite `x1 == x` in terms of `<=`, `>=`, or `compare`.

Comment: @melpomene but in my answer says that implements Eq, and that answers the question... What did I say wrong?

Comment: The only relevant part of this answer is "*also if you look at the type class definition you can see that Ord is subtype of Eq*", hidden in a subclause at the end. Everything else is irrelevant.

Comment: @DamianLattenero: did not dv, but in fact for Haskell whether it makes mathematically sense is not really an issue. For Haskell `<=`, and `==`, etc. are just (blackbox) functions. It does not know much/anything about the meaning behind `==`, it treats it as a function that takes two `a`s and returns a `Bool`, simple as that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for the comment, my idea wasn't that, now with your comment I edited and I think I could be claire, let me know please if now the answer is ok, please

Comment: @DamianLattenero You are giving an argument for why `Ord` should *imply* `Eq`, but that simply isn't relevant to the question. I can define a correct instance of `Ord` for a type like `data Z3 = One | Two | Three`, but the compiler will reject the code if I don't provide an `Eq` instance for the class as well (whether explicitly or derived). As Haskell stands, you don't get `==` unless you implement `Eq`.

Comment: @chepner thanks so much, now I see way it isn't claire and relevant, let me take your comment as example, and now please tell me if the updates  is ok for you

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I updated again the answer, let me know what you think please

Comment: @melpomene I will appreciate if you take another look at my answer, I'm trying to provide better answers to the community

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks it helps a lot to get better  :) you rules

Comment: Looking at this more, I'm surprised the documentation for `Ord` isn't explicit in stating that the `Ord` instance should be consistent with the required `Eq` instance. It's perfectly legal, for example, to write instances such that (using my `Z3`  example) `One == Two` is false, yet `One <= Two` and `Two <= One` are both true. If they are allowed to diverge, then why have a class constraint in the first place?

Comment: @chepner it's a good question for stack overflow maybe ;), will you post it? If you don't you put the doubt on me and now I want that answer... Interesting

Comment: @DamianLattenero I plan to, but I need to do some digging to make sure it isn't a duplicate first. (There appear to be several questions that touch on the issue, but nothing that directly addresses it or the reasons for it.)

Comment: @chepner so we don't now if my answer now is technically correct... To sad, so many edits and effort haha..

Comment: Well, the question only asks why you can use `==` without an explicit `Eq` constraint if you use `Ord`. You don't need to get into *why* `Ord` itself requires `Eq`. That said, the answer appears to be 1) `Ord` is intended to model total orders, which imply a definition of equality, and 2) the default implementation of `compare` uses `==`.